# How to calculate sum of the distance based on voltage cycle using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have pandas data frame which contains Voltage column and Distance column

```
data = {
    'Voltage': [52.59, 52.59, 51.01, 51.01, 49.63, 49.63, 54.59, 52.59, 51.01, 51.01, 49.63, 49.63],
    'Distance': [0, 0, 2.29, 0, 4.35, 0, 0, 0, 5.00, 0, 4.35, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

in Voltage I have two cycles one starts at 52.59 and ends at 49.63 within this range I want to sum the Distance and for second cycle start 54.59 and ends at 49.63 sum the Distance
my expected output is first cycle distance 6.64 and second cycle distance 9.35 how to do it using python thanks in advance

Comment: How do you determine a cycle?  Is it just when the numbers go back up again?  If so, this is pretty simple with a loop, although I don't think pandas will help you.  What have you tried?

Comment: actually this is electric vehicle data when voltage starting at maximum value and going down means considering as one cycle i want to determine with this cycle from 52.59 to end 49.63 how much distance the vehicle covered. i tried only pandas but not able to get output is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is not really required for this.

```
data = {
    'Voltage': [52.59, 52.59, 51.01, 51.01, 49.63, 49.63, 54.59, 52.59, 51.01, 51.01, 49.63, 49.63],
    'Distance': [0, 0, 2.29, 0, 4.35, 0, 0, 0, 5.00, 0, 4.35, 0]
}

dist = 0
last = 0
count = 0
for v,d  in zip(data['Voltage'],data['Distance']):
    if v > last:
        if dist:
            print( "Cycle", dist )
        dist = 0
    dist += d
    last = v

print( "Cycle", dist )
```

Output:

```
Cycle 6.64
Cycle 9.35
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculate diff of prev and current row in Voltage column to flag the rows where voltage is current row is greater than previous row, then calculate a cummulative sum on these flags to create a cycle counter, then group the dataframe by this counter and aggregate with sum

```
cycles = df['Voltage'].diff().gt(0).cumsum() + 1
result = df.groupby(cycles)['Distance'].sum()
```

---

```
 Voltage
1    6.64
2    9.35
Name: Distance, dtype: float64
```